# calling getter inside method Returns java.lang.NullPointerException with Activiti Engine

Tags: spring, activiti, bpmn

I'm working with Activiti engine in Spring +JSF project and i'm trying to call methods and pass parameters to my workflow via my process.BPMN20.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.bpmnwithactiviti.org"
    xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn">
    <process id="my-process" name="my-process">
        <startEvent id="startEvent" name="Start" activiti:formKey="taskForm_newOrder.jsf" />
    <sequenceFlow id="toValidateTask" sourceRef="startEvent" targetRef="validateTask"/>

    <serviceTask id="validateTask" activiti:expression="#{operationController.sayHello()}" >
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:field name="input" expression="${adminModele.operationLabel}" />
    </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>

    <sequenceFlow id="toCompletedOrderTask" sourceRef="validateTask" targetRef="completeOrderTask"/>
        <userTask id="completeOrderTask" name="Complete order" activiti:assignee="${adminModele.operationLabel}" activiti:formKey="taskForm_completeOrder.jsf">
      <documentation>Completing order for book with isbn : ${adminModele.operationLabel}  </documentation>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="toApproveTask" sourceRef="completeOrderTask" targetRef="approveTask"/>
    <serviceTask id="approveTask" activiti:expression="#{bookOrder.validates()}" />
    <sequenceFlow id="toEndEvent" sourceRef="approveTask" targetRef="endEvent"/>
        <endEvent id="endEvent" name="End"/>
    </process>
</definitions>
```

in here i set the value to the bookOrder

```
 bookOrder = new BookOrder();
    bookOrder.setIsbn("123");
    sayHello(); // this call doesn't return an error
```

the sayHello() method :

```
public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("SayHello ..."+bookOrder.getIsbn());
    }
```

When i call sayHello() it displays exactly what i want means the `bookOrder.getIsbn()` is not null , but when the Activiti engine calls it while going through the process i get :

```
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Error while evaluating expression: #{operationController.sayHello()}
            at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
            at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ma.net.s2m.selectsystem.web.controller.admin.OperationController.sayHello(OperationController.java:887)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:483)
```

Any ideas what's the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: What does the `getModele()` method do? Without knowing anything about it, it's impossible to say why it returns `null`.

Comment: the problem is not getModele() i tried a simple BookOrder book = new BookOrder() ,  i set value in my book when i call sayhello just to display book.getIsbn() it show the exact value but when activiti engine[ServiceTask] calls sayHello() i get nullPointerException

Comment: what is line 887 of `OperationController.java`? Something there is `null`. Looking at your code, it would be logical that `getModele()` returns `null` so that calling `getOperationLabel()` on that would cause an NPE.

Comment: 887 line is     System.out.println("SayHello..."+getModele().getOperationLabel()); yeaah the getModele is null but why ? i can call the same methode and it displays what i need , the problem the getModel or any other object becomes null when the ServiceTask calls sayHello

Comment: That's what you have to find out, but if you don't show us how the `getModele()` method is implemented and what it returns then it's very hard to help you with finding out why it returns `null`...

Comment: i edited the question , i set the value to the bookOrder and call sayHello() , this call doesn't return an error , after that activiti calls sayHello via ServiceTask and here the erros occurs